# Timestamp in blockheader

Tags: timestamp

Do bakers use current local time inside their baked block or forge timestamp by simply baking (last_block's timestamp + allowed_to_bake_time(1 min for priority 0, 2 min for priority 2 and so on)).

Comment: I would assume the bakers use Unix time and perform a physical time coordination based on Lamport's algorithms. But would be interesting to know more about the actual implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the vanilla baker uses the minimal timestamp, from the baking right (as you say, some delay after the previous priority/block): [client_baking_forge.ml](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_delegate/client_baking_forge.ml#L873).

However, you should not rely on this. A baker might choose any timestamp greater than the minimal timestamp. Your node will ignore the block (at the p2p layer) if it is more than 15s in the future.