# Since a blockchain has no concept of time, how do you determine if a baker baked “on time” or not?

Tags: baking, baking-rights

I understand that when a baker is chosen, they have a certain amount of time to bake before those rights are passed on to the second, third etc.

Since the blockchain itself has no concept of time, how is this determined?

Comment: See also related question: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/951/timestamp-in-blockheader

Answer (score 2):

Blocks in Tezos are timestamped and it is assumed that nodes have synchronized clocks with bounded clock skew.

Comment: Cool! Where can I read more about this? What is the clock skew value?

Comment: I don't think that's detailed somewhere. But my intuition is that broadcast blocks and operations need to be diffused to every node within 20 seconds (20 seconds for a new head to be propagated, and an additional 20 seconds for endorsements on that new head to be propagated, which together make the 40 seconds which are required between blocks at priorities higher than 0). The clock skew value can be seen as increasing the message propagation delays. So it should be small enough so that to not affect this 20 seconds upper bound.